# Do I need to buy a special stand for my front wheel when using my turbo trainer?

Tags: training, accessories, indoor

I have seen available special "stands" (please tell me the correct terminology) to be placed under the front wheel when using a turbo trainer.

I normally just put a copy of the phone directory down on the floor, opened in the middle to hold the wheel in place.

Should I lash out and buy one of the specialised devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nice advantage of the specialized stand is that it will keep your front wheel pointed front. So you won't have to expend energy keeping it that way. A brick or telephone directory (or anything that's just level and the right height) won't do that.

A piece of wooden plank will, after you hack away at it with an axe a few times right in the middle. If you're looking to save $20 it's the perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

My trainer came with the appropriate front stand.  However, I occasionally forget to use it and it really doesn't seem to matter either way.  Since I have it, I try to remember to use it, but if I didn't have it, I wouldn't bother to buy one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're anything like me, sooner or later your directory is going to be a pile of paper/sweat mush.

But until then this seems like a good hack provided the height is right and the wheel secure.

Answer (score 0):

I always found a house brick to be the perfect height and obviously nice and solid (and unaffected by sweat!)